# "London in England" vs. "London of England"

Tags: prepositions

How to write this sentence properly?

> "He lives in London **in** England."

Or:

> "He lives in London **of** England."

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is grammatically correct. the second is wrong.

Other ways to say it are:

> He lives in the English/British city of London.
>   or
>   He lives in London, the British capital.
>   or
>   He lives in London, in England rather than in (Ontario) Canada

(if you were specifying which London you were referring to)

But NEVER...**in London of England**.

Comment: I upvoted mostly for the third example, which I think raises an important point: most native speakers would simply say: _He lives in London_, with the "in England" part omitted unless the speaker thought that the hearer might think of a different London for some reason. (Also, one other way is to simply use a comma with no preposition, as in: _He lives in London, England,_ or, _He lives in Portland, Maine._)

Comment: What's interesting is that I can imagine somebody saying *in England's London* without a problem—perhaps in response to *Which London?* Although *in London of England* is something that doesn't seem normal to me, it's not something I would rule out as *wrong* in any way—aside from just not being idiomatic.